# Join with other table and get aggregated d

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table User and Score, each user have multiple score. How can I query average score with user name:

Ex:
Jack 6
Sham 5

User

```
Name    user_id
Jack   123
Tony   234
Sham   456
```

Score

```
id     score    user_id
1        4        123
2        8        123
3        9        234
4        2        456
5        10       456
6        3        456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, this is a `join` and `group by`:

```
select u.name, avg(s.score)
from users u join
     scores s
     using (user_id)
group by user_id, u.name;
```

Note that I've included `user_id` in the `group by`, in case two users have the same name.